# User removed - questions/answers deleted too?

Tags: support

When an user is removed you'll loose (or gain) some rep. Normally just a small amount like 10-30 so far. Yesterday I lost 110 ...

Is it possible that the removed user had a few answered questions, that have been deleted too? Or one question with 11 upvotes?

The question is not about the points, i just wonder if it is possible that answered questions are deleted. Normally you can not delete your questions if upvoted answers are there.

Comment: Even I lose 275 Rep, maybe  someone doing wrong stuff in site and admin removed that

Comment: not only you almost all regular user lost some reputation points, maybe some regular voter is deleted

Comment: Is there a way to know which account is deleted?

Comment: @ShoaibMunir I think only the mod who deletes that account only knows

Comment: If this is a contest..... I am at -545. :). I will look further to see what happened. But most probably you had some upvotes from the user(s) that got deleted.

Comment: @Marius if it just were votes (no answered questions deleted) it's as it is :)

Comment: @Marius Congrats for winning this contest ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@sv3n

If the user is  deleted then his/her answer remains as it is,

Here is the sample answer, where a user is deleted but the answer was there.

[Magento : Add customer login form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142507/magento-add-customer-login-form/142508#142508)

Above Example normal user deletes.

Now if user marked as spam then his/her associated post also deleted see below example **see user `user68158`**

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197187/after-updating-magento-1-9-3-6-customer-name-address-details-are-not-saving-in/228606

Comment: Yep. When a user is deleted, all of his/her posts are anonymized. The user name becomes `user<user-id-here>`. On the other hand, if a user is 'destroyed' (for spam for example) all the posts associated to that user are deleted also and all the flags on the posts are validated.

Comment: @Marius I add spam example also, I think sv3n can see deleted post as he also has 10k+ reputation

Comment: @Marius guess this is what I wanted to know ... "all the posts associated to that user are deleted". This mean valid answer are deleted too?!?

Comment: @sv3n mainly we have 8-10 examples where user-posted promotional content and ads then mods delete that user

Comment: @sv3n if user is regular user who posted answer regulary and he violate rulen then mods suspends those user for some periods

Comment: @sv3n for more please check this answer  https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/why-do-specific-user-has-been-suspended

Comment: @sv3n. If the user is "deleted", his/her posts remain by they become anonymous. If the user is "destroyed" all his/her posts are deleted.

Answer (score 1):

***As per, StackExchange policies, his/her votes will be invalidated after account deletion.So***

> The vote cast by that user is removed from your account.
>
> And that delete votes cannot be rolled back again.

Any questions asked by this user which have a score of 1  and 1-year-old, no answers, low views, etc will delete from StackExchange platform (Check below more details ). Rest of all is will exits.

### List of condition on which that user's question will remove from StackExchange.

**If the question is more than 30 days old, and**

```
has −1 or lower score
has no answers
is not locked
```

**... or ...**

> **It was closed and migrated to a different site**

**...or...**

> **it was migrated from a different site, and then rejected**

***it will be automatically deleted.***

### If the question is more than 365 days old, and ...

```
has a score of 0 or less, or a score of 1 and a deleted owner
has no answers
is not locked
has view count <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
has 1 or 0 comments
isn't on a meta site
```

***It will be automatically deleted.***

### If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and

```
not closed as a duplicate
has a score of 0 or less
is not locked
has no answers with a score > 0
has no accepted answer
has no pending reopen votes
has not been edited in the past 9 days
```

***It will be automatically deleted.***

Comment: This was not my question. What happens to users questions when his/her account is deleted?

Comment: Ahhh WTH :P ... thanks Amit, but this is something i know :) My question was "what happens to answered questions -> if a user is deleted?".

Comment: @sv3n, i hope that Marius & Murtuza Zabuawala give your question answer