# Why do specific user has been suspended?

Tags: discussion

I have come across a strange thing in SE today, the guy who has very good reputation and eventually today he has been suspended. I just literally went in shock like Is this a punishment? or what?

This profile name is [Rohan](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/51810/rohan-hapani?tab=profile) and I've gone through the penalty reason [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) . May I know the exact reason for such penalties. Just curious nothing else and if it is an offence just ignore it?

> NOTE : It has been stated as **the account has been suspended for promotional content**

What sort of thing that is exactly? Is the profile has been doing promotional activity inside the community?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rohan Hapani is suspended for 6 times at MSE for the different reasons like
promotional content, rule violations, voting irregularities.

He always broke the rules of the community even getting Annotation from moderator panel that's why this suspension happens. For now, he is suspended for 60day from 30th April.

After 60days, he will be back with his reputation and he can continue his contribution to the community.

**We hope that after this suspension, he will follow the community rule properly.**

Answer (score 2):

You will get full details here : [Defining the limits of self-promotion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86717/defining-the-limits-of-self-promotion)

i request moderators to suspend for a week for first time, what i feel is suspending one month is long period....

Comment: Baby, This is not an answer, Seems it is a request to the moderators. Please edit this answer. If you want to request, please add a new question in a requesting way.

Comment: it sounds romantic when you read the word "Baby" :)

Comment: FYI, since the mod has answered this question, apparently the user in question has been suspended more than 5 times, so this is certainly not the first time.

Comment: @AndrewT. you are right,  I did't know that, Mr.Amit posted answer later....